# Get List of All Folders In Google Drive - Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

Is there any way to get a list of all folders in "My Drive" using the Google Drive API. Here is the function I am trying to write.

```
function getAllFolders(){
    // Get all folders
}
```

(I looked at some other stack overflow posts but they weren't very helpful for me).

Comment: Follow this link - http://enarion.net/programming/php/google-client-api/google-client-api-php/

Comment: @DaImTo I'm sorry about that but "I looked at some other stack overflow posts [and] they weren't very helpful for me." In the future I will make sure to look more before coming here. Apologies.

Comment: @itsMeMoriarty im not asking you to look and copy someone else's code in another question.  I'm asking you to at least try to code things yourself and if you have issues come and ask for help.   Coding is a skill that is perfected though trial and error not copy paste from stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

With the query string `q`, you can search for files and folders following the syntax in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

Using `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` in the query string, to get just the folders.

there is a simple exemple:

```
<?php

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$folderID = "root";

$optParams = array(
            'pageSize' => 100,
            'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, modifiedTime, size, parents)',
            'q' => "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '".$folderID."' in parents"
        );
        
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
foreach ($results as $file) {
    // do somethings
}
```

Comment: I think I understand that part, but I'm not necessarily trying to search for a specific folder. I want to get a list of all folders within the root directory.

Comment: yes this code will help you, you just set the root to $folderID